# Getting this 'RenderContext' isn't a type. error on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
lib/view/screens/html/html_viewer_screen.dart:70:46: Error: 'RenderContext' isn't a type.
                    onLinkTap: (String? url, RenderContext context, Map<String, String> attributes, element) {
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/view/screens/html/html_viewer_screen.dart:68:23: Error: The method 'SelectableHtml' isn't defined for the class '_HtmlViewerScreenState'.
 - '_HtmlViewerScreenState' is from 'package:efood_multivendor/view/screens/html/html_viewer_screen.dart' ('lib/view/screens/html/html_viewer_screen.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'SelectableHtml'.
                  ) : SelectableHtml(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Script '/home/samier/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy' line: 1419
```